# I'm trying to get multiple long run probabilities

Tags: python, if-statement, long-running-processes

I'm trying to get the long run probabilities that Theme Parks, Cruise, Hiking, and  City Visits happen but for some reason it wont print out a probability that each will happen. Only a probability for 1. All 4 are suppose to add up to 1.

Any help?

[here is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2DYB.png)

Comment: Please post the source code as text, images are difficult to debug. Just paste the code and format it using Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the `break` statement in your code - it will abort the `for` loop after one iteration. Remove that and see how it goes.